# Gridview.SelectedRow returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code for displaying the gridview:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadCart();
            }

        }
        protected void LoadCart()
        {
            string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CartDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
            SqlDataAdapter SQLAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT M.menuItemName, M.menuItemImage,totalQuantity, M.menuItemPrice * totalQuantity Total_Price" +
                " FROM Cart C INNER JOIN itemSelected I ON C.username + C.itemSelectedID = I.username + I.itemSelectedID" +
                " INNER JOIN menuItem M ON I.menuItemID + I.stallID = M.menuItemID + M.stallID", SQLConn);
            
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            SQLAdapter.Fill(DT);
            CartGridView.DataSource = DT;
            CartGridView.DataBind();
            LoadPrice();
        }
        protected void LoadPrice()
        {
            string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CartDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(M.menuItemPrice * totalQuantity)tabulatedPrice" +
                " FROM Cart C INNER JOIN itemSelected I ON C.username + C.itemSelectedID = I.username + I.itemSelectedID" +
                " INNER JOIN menuItem M ON I.menuItemID + I.stallID = M.menuItemID + M.stallID", SQLConn);
            SQLConn.Open();
            lbl_TotalPrice.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
            SQLConn.Close();
        }
```

This is my code in attempting to retrieve a specific row, but it returns null.

```
protected void CartGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int result = 0;
            Cart cart = new Cart();
            GridViewRow row = CartGridView.SelectedRow;
            string itemName = row.Cells[0].Text;
            if (e.CommandName == "minusQuantity")
            {
                int quantity = int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Text) - 1;
                if (quantity > 0)
                {
                    cart.CartUpdateQuantity(quantity, itemName);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = cart.CartDelete(itemName);
                }

            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "addQuantity")
            {
                int quantity = int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Text) + 1;
                    cart.CartUpdateQuantity(quantity, itemName);
            }
            Response.Redirect("UserShoppingCart.aspx");
        }
```

And here is my aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Cart<table class="nav-justified">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 860px" class="modal-lg">Product</td>
            <td style="width: 698px">Images</td>
            <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 1265px">Quantity</td>
            <td>
                Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <asp:GridView ID="CartGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1514px" OnRowCommand="CartGridView_RowCommand" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product" ShowHeader="False" DataField="menuItemName" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Images" ShowHeader="False" DataField="menuItemImage" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="minusQuantity" Text="-" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Quantity" DataField="totalQuantity" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="addQuantity" Text="+" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Price" HeaderText="Price" ShowHeader="False" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 39px; " colspan="3">Total:<asp:Label ID="lbl_TotalPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 39px; width:50px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </h1>
    

</asp:Content>
```

Could this issue arise from having an Sql Table as the datasource?

I have attempted,

```
string itemName = CartGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

though it did work for the 1st row, I am uncertain on where to go next for the subsequent rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected index change does not fire untill after the row command.

Why not just drop in a plane jane regular button? That way you can style the button, and just have a regular and simple click event for the button.

So, change your markup button to this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdAddQty" runat="server" Text="+" 
                            OnClick="cmdAddQty_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

So, just type in OnClick= (in the markup, and you be prompted for create new event). the result is a simple plain jane button click.

So, then the button click code can be:

```
    protected void cmdAddQty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex);

        int quantity = int.Parse(gRow.Cells[3].Text) + 1;
        // cart.CartUpdateQuantity(quantity, itemName);

    }
```

So, you can easy pick up the row as per above.

And if you going to type "over and over" some sql, then build a helper rotuine to save world poverty, say like this:

```
protected void LoadCart()
{
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT M.menuItemName, M.menuItemImage,totalQuantity, M.menuItemPrice * totalQuantity Total_Price
        FROM Cart C 
        INNER JOIN itemSelected I ON C.username + C.itemSelectedID = I.username + I.itemSelectedID
        INNER JOIN menuItem M ON I.menuItemID + I.stallID = M.menuItemID + M.stallID";
    CartGridView.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
    CartGridView.DataBind();
    LoadPrice();
}
protected void LoadPrice()
{
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT SUM(M.menuItemPrice * totalQuantity)tabulatedPrice
        FROM Cart C 
        INNER JOIN itemSelected I ON C.username + C.itemSelectedID = I.username + I.itemSelectedID
        INNER JOIN menuItem M ON I.menuItemID + I.stallID = M.menuItemID + M.stallID";

    lbl_TotalPrice.Text = MyRst(strSQL).Rows[0][0].ToString();

}


DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CartDB"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

Last but not least?

It is great to use and learn webforms. But, that is as long as you NOT paying for such a course, since webforms are now quite old, and while still rather popular? They are quite much now older and a legacy choice, one that been superseded by MVC and newer approaches.

So, I think WebForms are great, but NOT if you paying for books or a course in this day and age, and those peddling books and course(s) that teach webforms are really just using older outdated material, and thus taking a horrible advantage of un-suspecting students that don't know better.

Anyway, just drop in a plain jane regular button. You can dispense with row command and all that song and dance, as it not really required, and a simple regular button and button click event is easier anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! Though it seems as though I ran into an error where it states that Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'usershoppingcart_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'cmdAddQty_Click' and no accessible extension method 'cmdAddQty_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'usershoppingcart_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well, this works JUST like ANY button you drop into a page. Often you will double click on a button to create the click event. In the markup, erase the onclick markup, then type in OnClick=      (WHEN you hit the "=" sign, then a popup in the editor should occur, and one of the options is to create new event. So, let the "system" create the click event. I mean, this is how most of us create a click event for a button. (the other being to double click on a button, but you can't double click on the button, since it now inside of the grid, so, use markup editor to add the click event.

Comment: so we NEVER manually type in a click event, but always let VS create the click event for you. As noted, comment out your existing click event that looks to be broken. Then in markup view, type in for the button OnClick=     ------ as noted, WHEN you hit "=", then a pop up should appear, and from that choose create new event. Now, flip back to code behind, and you should see the click event, and you can thus place your code inside of the click event. (this also means you dump/remove/don't have to use the onrow command, which as I noted is rather messy anyway, and you don't need it.